# How to properly make a custom 404 page in apache2

Tags: seo, html, php

My .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mywebsite.com/error_404.php
```

My error_404.php header

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");?>
```

Redirection works well but it seems like this configuration is not accepted by Google, This is a random page   Google Webmaster Fetch

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 13 Dec 2015 11:19:57 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.askcyan.com/error_404.php
Content-Length: 220
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/error_404.php">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: "Redirection works well" - that's the thing... for an error document you don't want it to "redirect". Ideally you want it to _internally rewrite_ the request. If it redirects then the first status code returned is a 3xx, not a 404.

Comment: It can pay off to not always reference the same domain name when referring to URLs on your own server, especially when dealing with URLs in anchor tags. It will make your code smaller and thus less server bandwidth and financial expenses will be required in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.php
```

Don't put the *absolute* URL in there - that's what's causing the redirect. Also, you don't need to set the 404 header through PHP - Apache will do that for you.